# Shape of weight variable Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to learn how to work with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset()` but I am confused about it. I have a `tfrecords` file which contains my images(24K) and labels and I have resized all my images to 100x100x3.

First, I loaded my `tfrecords` file with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` and parse the data and other stuff as you can see in my code. Then I wrote a simple model to learn the using of `tfrecord` file but I get stuck and getting error when trying to run. I have searched on the internet but couldn't find any answer.

Here is my code: **Train.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import  glob
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
batch_size = 128
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features = {"train/image": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
            "train/label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
  image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['train/image'], tf.float32)
  label = tf.cast(parsed_features['train/label'], tf.int32)
  image = tf.reshape(image, [100, 100, 3])
  image = tf.reshape(image, [100*100*3])

  return image, label

filename = 'train_data1.tfrecords'
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
#dataset = dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
image, label = iterator.get_next()


w = tf.get_variable(name='Weights',shape= [30000,3] , initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.01))
b = tf.get_variable(name='Biases', shape= [1, 3],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

logits = tf.matmul(image, w) + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=label, name='Entropy'), name='loss')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(preds, axis=1), tf.argmax(label, axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(2):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        total_loss = 0
        n_batches = 0
        try:
            while True:
                _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss])
                total_loss += l
                n_batches +=1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
        print('Average loss epoch {0}: {1}'.format(i, total_loss/n_batches))
```

and this is the output of image:

```
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(?, 30000) dtype=float32>
```

and label is:

```
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>
```

and this Time I got this error:

> logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[128,3]
>   labels_size=[1,128].

and when I reshape label (I think, I am doing wrong here) to [128,1] with `label = tf.reshape(label,[128,1])` I will get this error:

> imension size must be evenly divisible by 3 but is 128 for
>   'gradients/Entropy/Reshape_grad/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input
>   shapes: [128,1], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial
>   shapes: input[1] = [?,3].

I am trying to classify my 3 classes: 0 for bike, 1 for bus, and 2 for car.

this is the code how I read my images and label into `tfrecords`.
Code of **tfrecordWriter.py**

```
shuffle_data = True
cat_dog_train_path = './Train/*.jpg'
addrs = glob.glob(cat_dog_train_path)
labels = [0 if 'bike' in addr else 1 if 'bus' in addr else 2 for addr in addrs]

if shuffle_data:
    c = list(zip(addrs, labels))
    shuffle(c)
    addrs, labels = zip(*c)


train_addrs = addrs[:]
train_labels = labels[:]
train_shape = []
def load_image(addr):
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    return img


def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


train_filename = 'train_data1.tfrecords'
# open the TFRecords file
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(train_filename)
for i in range(len(train_addrs)):
    print ('Train data: {}/{}'.format(i+1, len(train_addrs)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    img = load_image(train_addrs[i])
    label = train_labels[i]
    feature = {'train/label': _int64_feature(label),
               'train/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from this line:

```
    w = tf.get_variable(name='Weights',shape= [None, 100, 100, 3] , initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.01))
```

You specified that your weights have shape `shape=[None,100,100,3]` which tensorflow can't handle. As the error says "Shape of a new variable (Weights) must be fully defined," so you can't have a `None` as a dimension of your weights. It looks to me like you confused the shape of the input tensor with the shape of the weights tensor. It also looks like you have not flattened your image anywhere, so your model is not really making any sense. Where you have:

```
    logits = tf.matmul(image, w) + b
```

it looks like you are trying to treat this problem as simple logistic regression with the pixels of the image as individual features. That's an ok first approach (but usually one would use a Conv-net on images), but you have to actually flatten your image into a shape of `shape=[batchsize,30000]`, then your weights would have a shape of `shape=[30000,num_labels]` so that at the end of the matrix multiplication you will have a final output of shape `shape=[batchsize,num_labels]`. Based on how your code is written, I feel like you have some fundamental misunderstandings of the mathematics or the operation behind what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe review what exactly it is you are trying to do.

EDIT: The problem here is a fundamental misunderstanding of what the algorithm is doing. The algorithm produces 3 outputs, and so the labels must have 3 corresponding labels to match the 3 outputs. Your labels can not be just one number - 0,1 or 2 depending on the class. Your labels must be 3 numbers, each number telling you whether you the image is in that class or not. In other words, you must label your images with a 3-component (one-hot) vector rather than a 1 component number. Your label for each image should look like this:

```
[1,0,0] - bike
[0,1,0] - bus
[0,0,1] - car
```

and so your label's shape `(128,3)` should be the **same** as the output shape `(128,3)`.

Comment: Thanks for guidance.I know, Usually Conv-net used on images. but my goal is to learn how to use Tfrecords file. 

I reshaped my images and made them flatten(tf.reshape(image, [100*100*3])) and now the shape of my images is (?, 30000). But still getting error. 

this time is: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[128,3] labels_size=[1,128]. my batch size is 128 and I have 3 classes. I have changed the label_size to [128, 1] but still is not working

Comment: 1. How many labels do you have? In other words, how many classes are you trying to classify the images into? 2. Please post (in an edit) your updated code so I can see what you did.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edit the post and add my tfrecord file writer which you may understand how my tfrecord it is

Comment: So, Should I change my label to one hot vector in tfrecordWriter.py or in train.py ? I mean where do I have to make them in one hot?

Comment: You can make them one-hot vectors anywhere as long as it's before the point where you feed them into the neural network itself.